# Tomcat shartup.sh command says permisison denied

Tags: permissions, tomcat7

I have set CATALINA_HOME in `~/.bashrc` file but on running

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

command it produces output like:

```
bash: /home/ravinder/Java_Folder/Important_Programs/Servers/Tomcat7/bin/startup.sh: Permission denied
```

Any help would be of great help.

Answer (score 4):

This error is due to wrong file permission and may be due to two reasons:

1. the file is not executable or
2. the user does not have privileges to run

In order to check try:

```
  ls -l /home/ravinder/Java_Folder/Important_Programs/Servers/Tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
```

If file is not executable fix it with:

```
  chmod +x $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

Or you could execute:

```
  bash $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

If your user doesn't have right privilege, for example file is executable only by root user, try this:

```
  sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

This latter case, it should not happen if tomcat has been installed properly and you should avoid running a web server with root privileges mainly for security reasons.

Comment: Very good - but running it as root with `sudo` should not be necessary, and should be avoided if possible. If the scripts need to be run as root to do something, it would probably give a different error.

Comment: @Wilf: yes, are you suggesting to remove this part of answer?

Comment: your choice - you could just put a warning next to it :-)

Comment: using this command ravinder@ravinder:~$ "ls -l /home/ravinder/Java_Folder/Important_Programs/Servers/Tomcat7/bin/startup.sh"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ravinder ravinder 1961 Jul  8 21:16 /home/ravinder/Java_Folder/Important_Programs/Servers/Tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
ravinder@ravinder:~$

Comment: using this command "chmod +x $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh" doesn't produces anything and the browser still says unable to connect to http://localhost:8080/

Comment: both the commands "bash $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh" and "sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh"
produce this  same output "Cannot find /home/ravinder/Java_Folder/Important_Programs/Servers/Tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh
The file is absent or does not have execute permission
This file is needed to run this program"

Comment: can you please tell me what is the problem. i am learning to use ubuntu. Thanks for your help..

Comment: As I can see, now the error is changed. This is due to `chmod +x` command. Now your `startup.sh` is executable and when you runs it you get a new error that means: `/home/ravinder/Java_Folder/Important_Programs/Servers/Tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh` has same problem of `startup.sh`. You should do `chmod +x /home/ravinder/Java_Folder/Important_Programs/Servers/Tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh` too.

Answer (score 1):

You may have downloaded the zipped version.

Download and extract the `tar.gz` format and it will work fine.

Comment: I found that these [Tomcat install steps](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-apache-tomcat-9-on-linux-rhel-centos/) worked for me.  They use tar.

Answer (score 0):

Execute following command:

```
ls -l {path_to _your_file}
```

See if the `user:group` credentials are similar to what you have in your `tomcat.service` file.

Answer (score -1):

just run chmod -R 777 {path to the bin directiry}, this will assign permissions to all sub-items of the bin directory.

Comment: That's a really bad idea.  That's like removing all the locks on your doors in your entire house because one key has a problem...

Comment: That's the quickest way to run locally, not to configure a live server.